# Insert external script after all items have been mounted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to attach an external script to my project, that binds a click event on elements. However, with my attempt it adds the script to the document with every item that's mounted.

So in `components/shop/Shop.js`

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = 'https://embed.selly.gg';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
    console.log('updated');
}
```

And I'm attaching it to `components/shop/ShopItem.js`

```
<button className={classes.button} data-selly-product-{product.id}>
    Buy
</button>
```

So I want to only attach the script once, but bind all of the items with the event that the script includes. How do I do this?

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. Does componentDidMount not work? This depends on your case which didn't explained well.

Comment: If you really have to do this perhaps find a parent element with a ref and then add the listener to that. Then it will be simpler to remove it with `componentWillUnmount`. Isn't this code available as a module tha you can import?

Comment: @estus there's multiple shopitems and this as it is inserts into the page multiple times.

Comment: Can't you do this once for all existing items? If you can't this doesn't seem like a good idea because the script obviously wasn't designed to work with SPA that may change with time. Items won't be destroyed, this will result in memory leaks.

Comment: :/ I just want this to work.